# Angular 8 process.env returns always undefined

Tags: typescript

I am running bash on Debian 9.11

export SERVER_DB="my_server"

in any typescript module :

import * as process from 'process';
process.env.SERVER_DB

returns undefined

What is missing ?

Comment: Angular applications are executed inside the browser, by the browser JS engine. Not by NodeJS on the server. There is no such thing as `process` in client-side JavaScript. That's a NodeJS thing.

Comment: Thank you. I have two more questions: 1) why typescript accepts process.env ? 2) how may I get the value of an environment variable from typescript ?

Comment: TypeScript is a programming language. The program you write in TS can run in various environment, including the browser. The browser doesn't provide any environment variable.